# Redirecting PyUnit output to file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev, python-unittest

Is there a built-in way in Eclipse to redirect PyUnit's output to a file (~ save the report)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output can be easily redirected to a file in **Run Configurations** > **Common** tab > **Standard Input and Output** section. Hiding just in plain sight...